# Encrypt and sign in Nodejs, validate signature in php

Tags: php, node.js, rsa, phpseclib, php-openssl

I would like to encrypt and sign certain data in nodejs and validate the signature in php. I keep on getting this error:

> error:04091077:rsa routines:int_rsa_verify:wrong signature length

I have tried to change the algorithm being used, Also tried php extension such as phpseclib. In Nodejs am using the `"crypto": "^1.0.1"`. Also this openssl_verify in php.

Here is my nodejs code

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

module.exports = {

    generateKey: () => {


    return   { publicKey, privateKey } = generateKeyPairSync('rsa', {
            modulusLength: 2048,
            publicKeyEncoding: {
                type: 'spki',
                format: 'pem'
            },
            privateKeyEncoding: {
                type: 'pkcs8',
                format: 'pem',

            }

      });
    },

    encryptMessage: (message) => {
        const config = new Configstore(packageJson.name);
        const algorithm = 'aes-256-cbc';
        const key = config.get('serverKey');
        const iv = crypto.randomBytes(16);
        let cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', Buffer.from(key), iv);
        let encrypted = cipher.update(message);
        encrypted = Buffer.concat([encrypted, cipher.final()]);

        return { iv: iv.toString('hex'), encryptedData: encrypted.toString('hex')};

    },

    signMessage: (message) => {
        console.log(message);
        const config = new Configstore(packageJson.name);
        const sign = crypto.createSign('SHA256');
        sign.update(message);
        sign.end();
        const signature = sign.sign(config.get('privateKey'),'base64');

        const verify = crypto.createVerify('SHA256');
        verify.update(message);
        verify.end();
        console.log(config.get('publicKey'));
        console.log('Its working: ' + verify.verify(config.get('publicKey'), signature, 'base64'));
        return signature;
    }

}
```

Here is php:

```
public function saveSecreteMessage(Request $request) {

        $request->validate([
            'username' => 'required',
            'secretName' => 'required',
            'secretMessage' => 'required'
        ]);

        $publicKey = User::where('username', $request->input('username'))->first();

        if (!$publicKey) {
            return response()->json('Not allowed', 401);
        }

        $data = $request->input('secretMessage')['encryptedData'];
        $signature = $request->input('secretMessage')['signature'];

    /*    $rsa = new RSA();
        $rsa->loadKey($publicKey->publicKey); // public key;
        return $rsa->verify('message', $signature, 'base64') ? 'verified' : 'unverified';*/

        $ok = openssl_verify(base64_encode($data),  base_path($signature), $publicKey->publicKey, 'SHA256');

        if ($ok == 1) {
            return response()->json('', 200);
        } else {
            return response()->json(openssl_error_string(), 400);
        }

        $pet = $request->all();
        return $pet;
    }
```

I expect the php code to validate the signature sent over from nodejs. I can't seem to get it to work. The error I get is:

> error:04091077:rsa routines:int_rsa_verify:wrong signature length

Comment: Your example does not contain code that can be used to easily reproduce the issue. Sure, it can be finagled but it has to be finagled but it shouldn't have to be. `$publicKey = User::where('username', $request->input('username'))->first();` for example will not work without that Laravel model / table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working.

JS code:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

keyPair = crypto.generateKeyPairSync('rsa', {
            modulusLength: 2048,
            publicKeyEncoding: {
                type: 'spki',
                format: 'pem'
            },
            privateKeyEncoding: {
                type: 'pkcs8',
                format: 'pem',

            }

      });

var message = "zzzz";

const sign = crypto.createSign('SHA256');
sign.update(message);
sign.end();

const signature = sign.sign(keyPair.privateKey,'base64');

console.log(keyPair.publicKey);
console.log(signature);
```

PHP code:

```
$rsa = new RSA;
$rsa->loadKey('-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA1e4Gi38Dlyl41RSGnQAK
UsHONpX806tFD3fuOby3JQlhlDM+Pe/H8y6E/zMDtNSZXtO+QCqghtMLDVG2br9e
i8uvGFwxLFUaWVkOYY7Tz21vJYYclvn67y0fJE8jgKUOdl3fgv/H3IGRVTROOetH
4oMpHMTGRpjZFfI6mi7CSDiaR8D1EpmPeXJn8yYPHK4uDn5srhZDQTvXXwbYkskX
FjbSx3yKvu1wkwKbKU5GkbBCzsFlNDhlCN4fvZ9SjinnV1iARgB80qIQlQ6JAUpp
xM/bTUntjI73DHCF3dXv9pbwn6w/vfjoyxstwAzgp+7C8HuaVm12KOeKG5Lsbj/L
XwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----');

$plaintext = 'zzzz';
$signature = base64_decode('Vzc+63A5nAZWwIPD99pJQkzR7JfOhG0xyaTQh+Pel2wWklnzN9lTibwhliJs7tyZlJzjZrhgS2reTDd26HqLw11RDbqMCxim/InOiuFPbOg8EgNt55mNyfICszt+2ZVa1Mjm8zXpFBvNee5EPPFbqoCRKUpulDiGwRVz8v6rgSrx+Ptl11dIXyQuTa90bTdJEHiGK73F/uPh/B9AQOVYkoJKA4GC8H7pC3+AiTBREeBfRZp7gMF3wq2pYS5ffGemxsIkKuVoDurVNSJL9xWF10H3nn0egpIDwDQLYdilrVAUW7z+Qu6lQ2FxNiFSX0TT6gL02WN5/UxCVokCSnufkg==');

$rsa->setSignatureMode(RSA::SIGNATURE_PKCS1);
$rsa->setHash('sha256');

echo $rsa->verify($plaintext, $signature) ? 'good' : 'bad';
```